# When can I user Meteor.call synchronously?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The documentation says

> Finally, if you are inside a stub on the client and call another
>   method, the other method is not executed (no RPC is generated, nothing
>   "real" happens). If that other method has a stub, that stub stands in
>   for the method and is executed. The method call's return value is the
>   return value of the stub function. The client has no problem executing
>   a stub synchronously, and that is why it's okay for the client to use
>   the synchronous Meteor.call form from inside a method body, as
>   described earlier.

But I have no idea what this means. What's a stub? How can I run it in a stub? Is an event a stub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Meteor.call synchronously only on the server.

A 'stub' is a `Meteor.methods` that runs on the client side. Usually it runs on the server side.

When it runs on the client side it doesn't really do anything, which is why its a stub. This can be useful for simulating what it could do to create the effect of latency compensation.

E.g you could have

```
Meteor.call("create_something", function(err,result) { alert(result) });
```

Then on your server side

```
Meteor.methods({
    create_something: function() {
         SomeCollection.insert({date: new Date()});
    }
});
```

So when you run the `Meteor.call` it would insert the record on the server. If the client is subscribed to the client it will also get this result, but after a while - due to the latency between the server and client.

If you add the stub method to the client side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    create_something: function() {
         SomeCollection.insert({date: new Date()});
    }
});
```

Now if you do it, the client side one will add this simulated-non real record, until the server returns a result.

The idea of it is to make the UI more responsive, and to make `Meteor.call` as instantaneous (ui-wise) as `SomeCollection.insert` directly on the client.

Comment: So If I have a stub (client-side method) and a server-side method, then they both run. But I can effectively treat it async on the client because it simulated what the server would do.